# MS-Access query returning duplicate results how do I prevent this

Tags: ms-access

I'm running into 2 issues with a query I've made.  The first being that it is extremely slow going through 58000 records.  The second is that I'm getting duplicate AccountID in my results.

For the duplicate field I believe I'm missing a criteria, but haven't figured out which one.

How can I change the query to address both of these issues?

Input:

```
Account startdate   enddate     AccountID
00001   5/1/2015    5/1/2017    63854
00001   5/1/2017    5/1/2020    73104
00002   4/1/2012    4/1/2014    23764
00002   4/1/2014    4/1/2017    54492
00003   12/1/2012   5/1/2014    43104
00003   5/1/2014    5/1/2015    59321
00003   5/1/2014    5/1/2015    59421
00004   10/1/2012   10/1/2014   42844
00004   10/1/2014   2/1/2017    55481
00004   10/1/2014   2/1/2017    55481
00006   10/1/2014   2/1/2017    55401
00006   10/1/2018   2/1/2019    55402
```

Code:

```
SELECT dups.account, 
   dups.startdate, 
   dups.enddate, 
   dups.accountid 
INTO   [renewal tags] 
FROM   dups, 
   dups AS Dups_1 
WHERE  ( ( ( dups.account ) = [dups_1].[account] ) 
     AND ( ( dups.startdate ) = [dups_1].[enddate] ) 
     AND ( ( dups.accountid ) <> [dups_1].[accountid] ) ) 
    OR ( ( ( dups.account ) = [dups_1].[account] ) 
         AND ( ( dups.enddate ) = [dups_1].[startdate] ) 
         AND ( ( dups.accountid ) <> [dups_1].[accountid] ) );
```

Output:

```
Account startdate   enddate AccountID
00001   5/1/2015    5/1/2017    63854
00001   5/1/2017    5/1/2020    73104
00002   4/1/2012    4/1/2014    23764
00002   4/1/2014    4/1/2017    54492
00003   12/1/2012   5/1/2014    43104
00003   5/1/2014    5/1/2015    59321
00003   5/1/2014    5/1/2015    59421
00004   10/1/2012   10/1/2014   42844
00004   10/1/2014   2/1/2017    55481
00004   10/1/2014   2/1/2017    55481
```

Desired Output:

```
Account startdate   enddate     AccountID
00001   5/1/2015    5/1/2017    63854
00001   5/1/2017    5/1/2020    73104
00002   4/1/2012    4/1/2014    23764
00002   4/1/2014    4/1/2017    54492
00003   12/1/2012   5/1/2014    43104
00003   5/1/2014    5/1/2015    59321
00003   5/1/2014    5/1/2015    59421
00004   10/1/2012   10/1/2014   42844
00004   10/1/2014   2/1/2017    55481
```

Answer (score 0):

I should have used an inner join and made sure account IDs from the table didn't match against itself in the join criteria.  This solved both problems.  The corrected code is below.

```
SELECT dups.accountid, 
   dups.accountnumber, 
   dups.startdate, 
   dups.enddate 
INTO   [renewal tags] 
FROM   dups 
   INNER JOIN dups AS Dups_1 
           ON dups.accountnumber = Dups_1.accountnumber 
              AND dups.accountid <> dups_1.accountid 
WHERE  (( ( dups.startdate ) = [dups_1].[enddate] )) 
    OR (( ( dups.enddate ) = [dups_1].[startdate] ));
```